# What is the logback equivalent for log4j %u{RANDOM}

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

I need to generate a random uuid number from logback, 
I used  %u{RANDOM} in log4j, now I am looking same functionality in logback
Any help will be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add the UUID to the MDC and then use %X{uuid} to include it.

Answer (score 0):

example logback.xml

```
<encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
    <providers>
         <uuid>
            <fieldName>event</fieldName>
         </uuid>
    </providers>
</encoder>
```

[readme or docs](https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder)